# processing alternate line bash

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file like this

```
line1
this is line1
line2
this is line2
line3
this is line3
```

I wanted to use awk or sed to remove trailing newline characters at every alternate line to merge them like this

```
line1: this is line1    
line2: this is line2
line3: this is line3
```

How do I do it using awk or sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat input 
line1
this is line1
line2
this is line2
line3
this is line3
$ awk 'NR%2==1 {prev=$0} NR%2==0 {print prev ": " $0} END {if (NR%2==1) {print $0 ":"}}' input
line1: this is line1
line2: this is line2
line3: this is line3
$
```

Comment: This should prevent the vanishing: `awk 'NR%2==1 {prev=$0} NR%2==0 {print prev ": " $0} END {if (NR%2==1) {print $0 ":"}}' input` (by the way, redirection isn't necessary).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks! That's nicer than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '${s/$/:/p};N;s/\n/: /p' inputFile
```

For  in-place editing with backup of original file,

```
sed -n -i~ '${s/$/:/p};N;s/\n/: /p' inputFile
```

Comment: This should prevent the disappearance: `sed -n '$p;N;s/\n/: /p'` or `sed -n '${s/$/:/;p};N;s/\n/: /p'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '$!N;s/\n/: /' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^\(line.*\)/\1:/' filename | paste - -
```

And the Perl analogue:

```
perl -ape 's/^(line.+)\n/$1: /' filename
```